# Fill the transparent part of the drawable with a specific color

Tags: android, xml, android-imagebutton

I have this transparent image that I want to fill a specific color inside of the transparent part.

[image]

I have been able to fill up this image a specific color I want, but the problem is that the color is also filling up the outside part of the `ImageButton`.

Here is the sample:

[image]

How can I remove the excess red color outside of the drawable?

Here is my current **xml:**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_scan"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_scan"
    android:background="@color/aub_red"
    android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
    android:textColor="@color/edittext_text" />
```

Comment: Try removing this: `android:background="@color/aub_red"`

Comment: Because your drawable size is smaller than `ImageButton`.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån then how can i fill a color in the transparent part of the drawable?

Comment: @netflixspotify: try setting `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Your image is Square and your button is Rectangular @netflixspotify Use a button with square shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to build by adding theses

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

if your image ratio affected by above change you can use

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: @netflixspotify nice to hear it. It is good for me if u can upvote this as well.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the parent is a LinearLayout with some 'weightsum', which is why the width of the ImageButton is uncertain.

You could create a framelayout which would contain this imagebutton and another layout (with the same width and height as the imagebutton) underlying the imagebutton. Something like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/aub_red"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_scan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen" />
</FrameLayout>
```